# Multiply rows in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, rows

Im trying to multiply a row of a matrix by a number.

This is my code:

```
def multiply_rows(m,r,x):
for i in range(r,r +1):
    for j in range(0,m.shape[1]):
        m[i,j] = (m[i,j]) * (1 / float(x))
return m
```

This is what the console gave me:

```
multiply_rows(numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]]),1, 4)
```

array([[1, 2],
       [0, 1]])

I can't understand why does it shows a 0 instead of 0,75. All help is welcome

Comment: Mahybe use `1.0` instead of `1`.

Comment: @Divakar it doesnt work

Comment: @Divakar but thanks!

Comment: Well because your input `numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])` is an int array. It can't hold float values. Change that to a float one.

Comment: @Divakar thank you, it works!!!!!!!! So there is no way to put and int array and give me a float array?

Comment: Nope, there's no such magic. Or just create a float copy inside that func.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `m*(r/float(x))`. Numpy should take care of multiplying.

```
x = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
x*(1/4)

Output: array([[0.25, 0.5 ],
       [0.75, 1.  ]])
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm doing this because im trying to do an algorithm to invert a matrix without using numpy functions. So this fuction will do one task only. Thank your for the help